# Does anyone know a html to pdf converter which uses curl instead of fopen?

Tags: php, curl, fopen, html2pdf

I am looking for a html2pdf php script, which uses curl to open/check images. Our server doesn't allow the fopen function.

Thanks!

*** EDIT ***

I solve the issues by replacing the fopen function with curl and the getimagesize with curl in combination with imagecreatefromstring. Its not the best solution, but it works for now!

Comment: Any service that supports `fopen` would support `curl` .. what service are you using currently ??

Comment: I have tried html2fpdf and html2pdf (french one)

Answer (score 0):

htmlToPdf does not need "fopen" or "file_get_contents". It takes a HTML string and formate it as PDF.
the fopen utilisation is only a tool that can be used *if you want* but it is not *the* tool.

So get your HTML with your curl function and then pass it to [html2pdf](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://html2pdf.fr/&ei=6QleUK_7GuGw0QX3qYDADQ&usg=AFQjCNHu9QWyOA4TDAzRQLXPXW2NaKZCHg&sig2=j0ChEUTxGXFoYKSwEPPrzQ) for example or the pdf parser that is [compatible to ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.create.html) and is [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) so can be easily loaded.

As you need to get image when the html is transformed to PDF, you will need to use curl as a stream abstraction. 
In PHP, there is a very powerful tool that can [wrap a stream](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) and give it an indentifier. For example "http://" is a stream implemented by default that uses a http request.
the problem is that no tool will use curl directly, they will prefer use this abstraction as it is accessible with fopen whatever protocole you will use.
And as you have your allow_url_fopen instruction desactivated in your ini file, whatever you'll do, it will fail.

So there is a trick you can use :
get all your img tag with regex ([preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) would be great), and parse the datas step by step.

Comment: The ones I tried needed fopen for image support. getimagesize and fopen to check if the image exists.

Comment: I can't remember if curl is a standard php stream but you can wrap it inside the function that are needed and throw a `str_replace('http://','curl://',$htmlObject);`

Comment: I added some precisions to my answer